# Alternative way to select an element which comes before a specific element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am working on creating a simplified bespoke framework for structuring forms by only adding or removing html elements and without using classes or JavaScript.

After days of work, below is a demonstration of what I manged to do so far:

[image]

The only problem I am experiencing is highlighted in yellow circles above.

I simply can't get the input/textarea which is followed by an `<i>` or `<a>` to keep its original `border-radius`, which is set to `4px` in this line of CSS:

```
/*(?) Form elements global border-radius settings*/
input, textarea, select, .select-input, fieldset > div > span,fieldset > div > a {
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

The full HTML and CSS which used to show the image above can be found in this JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/kvezedo5 - I have also uploaded a live version of the framework shown in the image above here: http://loai.directory/test

The HTML for the elements in question are below:

```
<fieldset>
   <div>
      <input name="">
      <i class="icon-question tooltip-top" title="Text Goes Here"></i>
   </div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
   <div>
      <input name="">
      <a>Button</a>
   </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Could you include the portions of your markup that are problematic within the question?

Comment: Could you not turn it around, and instead selecting a element *after* the specific element? For that there's the simple `+` in CSS.

Comment: @Daniel Lisik: How would you apply border-radius then?

Comment: Sorry guys, I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

The culprit is this:

```
fieldset > div > *:first-child:not(:last-child) {
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
```

You should change that to use a class so it doesn't clobber everything. This is the reason global selectors aren't usually recommended:

```
fieldset > div > .sharpcorners
```

Comment: I was hopping I can get it all working with pure CSS, as you can see it is practically done but only that little problem is on the way. No other suggestions, please?

Comment: That is pure CSS, all you need to do is add a class to the input element.